# Formato incorrecto al añadir objetos a un json utilizando dump

Tags: python, json, test, jsonobject

Estoy creando una función que añade objetos a un archivo .json si el objeto que se desea añadir no está en el archivo. Además, si el archivo no existe debe crearlo. Sin embargo, tengo un problema con el formato del archivo json, de forma que al añadir más de un objeto la función load es incapaz de leerlo.
Esta es la clase en una versión más sencilla:

```
class AccessRequest:
"""Class representing the access request"""
def __init__(self, id_document, full_name, access_type, email_address, validity):
    self.id_document = id_document
    self.full_name = full_name
    self.visitor_type = access_type
    self.email_address = email_address
    self.validity = validity
    self.__time_stamp = 1616582510.564338
```

Y este es el código para manejar el json:

```
try:
with open("myFile.json", "r", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)
    
    with open("myFile.json", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as modify_file:
        check = False

        for element in data:
            json.dump(accessRequestData2.__dict__, modify_file, indent=2)
            
            if element._AccessRequest__id_document == accessRequestData.id_document:
                check = True
            
        if check==False:
            json.dump(accessRequestData.__dict__, modify_file, indent=2)

 except FileNotFoundError as ex:
    with open("myFile.json", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as create_file:
        json.dump(accessRequestData.__dict__, create_file, indent=2)
```

Gracias.

Comment: Recomendación en vez de abrir el archivo dos veces ábrelo una sola vez con ambos permisos ```r+``` y también cierra los ficheros

Comment: Samuel, me ha llamado la atención que has recibido respuestas aparentemente de muy buena calidad a tus preguntas y no has aceptado ninguna. ¿Es por alguna razón en particular? Si se te ha escapado cómo hacerlo, te invito a darte una vuelta por el [tour]. También lee esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que usas `json.dump()` estás creando un nuevo "objeto" JSON. El fichero resultante por tanto no contiene un solo objeto, sino varios seguidos (probablemente uno por línea). Estrictamente hablando eso no es JSON válido, sino que sería más bien un formato popularmente conocido como [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/)

La función `json.load()` espera un solo objeto JSON y no uno por línea. Por eso fracasa. Hay una librería llamada [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para leer ese tipo de archivo, pero no forma parte de la librería estándar python y no sé si te merece la pena instalarla.

El problema puedes resolverlo leyendo el fichero línea a línea y usando `json.loads()` para convertir cada una de esas líneas. Puedes ir concatenando en una lista los objetos que así vayas leyendo. Algo como esto:

```
import json

lista = []
with open("myFile.json", "r") as f:
  for linea in f:
     lista.append(json.loads(linea))
```

Naturalmente para que esto funcione los objetos JSON deben haberse volcado cada uno en una sola línea, por lo que tendrás que cambiar la opción `indent=2`, que te lo formateaba "bonito", por `indent=None` que lo volcará sin formatear, todo en en una línea (cada objeto) en la forma más compacta posible.

### Otra posibilidad

Otra idea es que en lugar de generar un fichero tipo JSON Lines, generes un JSON válido. Para ello no puedes volcar un objeto tras otro sin más, sino que debes volcar una lista de objetos, de modo que al fichero irían a parar separados por comas y encerrado todo entre un `[` inicial y un `]` final.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```
lista_a_volcar = []
check = False
for element in data:
   lista_a_volcar.append(accessRequestData2.__dict__)
   if element["_AccessRequest__id_document"] == accessRequestData.id_document:
      check = True
if not check:
   lista_a_volcar.append(accessRequestData.__dict__)
```

Para después volcarla simplemente:

```
with open("myFile.json", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as modify_file:
  json.dump(lista_a_volcar, modify_file, indent=2)
```

Por consistencia yo modificaría también la creación del fichero para que vuelque una lista como en el caso anterior, aún si esa lista tiene un solo elemento, es decir, usaría `json.dump([accessRequestData.__dict__], create_file, indent=2)`